# Subtotal of subtotals shows zero

Tags: excel

I'm seeing a strange behavior with Excel's subtotal function.

In cells A1:A2 I have the values `1` and `2` respectively.
In cell B2 I have the formula `=Subtotal(9,A1:A2)` which correctly displays `3`.
In cell B1 I have the formula `=Subtotal(9,B2:B2)` which incorrectly displays `0`.

Why is this and what are common workarounds?

I don't think a PivotTable will do it for my setup. I noticed that I can set cell C2 to `=B2` and then setting C1 to `=Subtotal(9,C2:C2)` gives the correct result but it feels very hackish to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid double-counting, subtotalling a range ignores sub-totals within that range. A workaround is =`B2` in B1.